# Law Of Variable Proportions

Tags: microeconomics

In the Law of Variable Proportions, it is said that a producer prefers to work in the second phase where it is the phase of diminishing returns while number of variable factors are increased. But shouldn't they prefer to work in the first phase where there are increasing returns?

Doesn't increasing returns seem to be a better possibility for producers rather than diminishing returns?